# Android random black screens

Tags: java, android

So I have a POS system built in Java/Android.  In my development environment, this never happens, but my clients are experiencing occasional "black screens".  It happens on random activities/fragments and there is no crash error.  The screen just turns black, you can see the android time and status on the top right.  Users need to close out all apps and then return to the app and everything is fine again.

I have gone through all the warnings on these pages and cleaned up various possible memory leaks but I would think if it WAS a memory leak we would get an error.  I have no idea on how to diagnose what is going on.  What are the possibilities here?  Could it be a memory leak?  It's happening on different tablets (Galaxy Tab A 10.1) so I have ruled out a defective unit.  All of my web service calls are done async...

What should I do to fix an error that I can't reproduce and doesn't cause a crash?